# How to get Request.Form["elementName"] of an element while it has the attribute runat="server"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, runatserver, request.form

So, I have an element:

```
<input id="loginEmail" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email" />
```

I can get it using `Request.Form["email"]`

While when I use the following:

```
<input id="loginEmail" runat="server" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email" />
```

Note: I added `runat="server"` it doesn't work. How can I retrieve the data without using `loginEmail.Value`?

The reason I want to do this is to preserve the input value after the method is run, like so(should the submission not work out and I show an error message for the user to edit the values of the form):

```
loginEmail.Value = Request.Form["email"];
```

Thank you all.

Comment: So am I correct in saying that you want to preserve the value across the normal postback?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! That is the whole reason as to why I am doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not a server control you select your input control's value by name. If it's a server control you need to select it by Id.

```
Request.Form["loginEmail"]
```

Use `Request.Form.AllKeys` to check what's sent and how it's sent.

Answer (score 1):

Although @Schadensbegrenzer answer might be of your use but conceptually it is wrong. `Request.Form` will only give you value if `name` is passed.

Mentioned answer is working for you because `ASP.Net` will automatically add `name` attribute with the value same as `id` if you don't specify it. So here id = name and you are picking is based on `name` only.

You can just have name that is different from id with `runat = server` and try to pick value based on id, it will give you `null`.

The answer is you question is "It is impossible".

Comment: @yaharga glad to hear that.